# How to assign string value for one column depending on string value in another string value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a dataframe:

```
Name | Assignment Group
ABC | 1
DEF | 1
FGH | 1
ABC | 1
IJK | 1
```

I now want to assign a specific `Assignment Group` depending on column `Name`.
E.g.: Name `ABC` and `IJK` belong to group `A` and `DEF` as well as `FGH` to `B`.

In the end I want to get a dataframe like this:

```
Name | Assignment Group
ABC | A
DEF | B
FGH | B
ABC | A
IJK | A
```

How can I do this in python? It would be okay to do this group by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `map()`:

```
d={'A':['ABC','IJK'],'B':['DEF','FGH']}
#created a dict for mapping values
df['Assignment Group']=df['Name'].map({i:k for k,v in d.items() for i in v})
```

OR

via `replace()`:

```
df['Assignment Group']=df['Name'].replace({i:k for k,v in d.items() for i in v})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and map to it.

```
>>> fnames = {'ABC': 'A', 'DEF': 'B', 'FGH': 'B', 'IJK': 'A'}
>>> df
  Name  Assignment Group
0  ABC                 1
1  DEF                 1
2  FGH                 1
3  ABC                 1
4  IJK                 1

>>> df['Assignment'] = df['Name'].map(fnames)
>>> df = df.drop('Assignment Group', axis=1)
>>> df
  Name Assignment
0  ABC          A
1  DEF          B
2  FGH          B
3  ABC          A
4  IJK          A
```

Or you can use `lambda` with `map()` as follows:

```
>>> df['Assignment Group'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: 'A' if 'ABC' in x else 'A' if 'IJK' in x else 'B')
>>> df
  Name Assignment Group
0  ABC                A
1  DEF                B
2  FGH                B
3  ABC                A
4  IJK                A
```

You can write a function as well:

```
def map_rows(row):
    if row == 'ABC':
        return 'A'
    elif row == 'IJK':
        return 'A'
    return 'B'
```

use `apply()` with custom function:

```
>>> df['Assignment Group'] = df['Name'].apply(map_rows)
>>> df
  Name Assignment Group
0  ABC                A
1  DEF                B
2  FGH                B
3  ABC                A
4  IJK                A
```